# "the tangent line to a circle" vs. "the line tangent to a circle"

Tags: word-order, postpositive-adjectives

Consider:

> the tangent line to a circle
>
> the nearest house to the state-house
>
> a cheap compatible battery with my aging APC UPS

Do the following examples have the same syntactic structure and sound equally idiomatic? Which one would be preferred?

> the line tangent to a circle
>
> the house nearest to the state-house
>
> a cheap battery compatible with my aging APC UPS

Comment: "the tangent line to a circle" What does that mean?

Comment: Are you trying to say each pair has the same meaning? Or just that they have some valid usage somehow?

Comment: A line is tangent to a curve or circle at a given point, but a "tangent line" is not really specific.

Answer (score 2):

These are all idiomatic:

**The house nearest to the state house.

A line tangent to a circle.

A cheap  battery compatible with my aging APC UPS**

Enough people say this to consider it idiomatic:

**The  nearest house to the state house.**

This is idiomatic:

**a compatible battery for my aging APC UPS**

But this is not:

**a compatible battery with my aging APC UPS**

because the phrase is "compatible with".

Not enough data on this one, since it's from a specific domain, not something you hear people saying very often:

**A tangent line  to a circle.**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles Lots of results came up when you search it in the Google Books.

Comment: "Not something you *hear* people saying very often".

Answer (score 1):

**Phrase 1**

Idiomatic? you gotta be kidding. Tangent is a technical word. For technical stuff, you go for precise meaning, not idiom. Get the exact phrasing for the meaning that you want from a reliable technical document.

**Phrase 2**

> the nearest house to the state-house

sounds better, because the second should really be

> the house [that is] nearest to the state-house

Why use a phrase that has bits missed out, when you can use a phrase that doesn't need those bits in the first place? Both are correct, but the first is more natural.

**Phrase 3**

Two adjectives. "cheap" doesn't have any baggage, but "compatible" must be next to the preposition "with", and "with" must be next to "my ageing APC ups". The only grammatically correct sentence is:

> a cheap battery compatible with my aging APC UPS

Comment: The 2nd sense: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic